# Cannot find 'AIMobileLib' in scope : Login With Amazon - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, login-with-amazon

I am trying to implement LWA in my iOS app. I used the resources from :

https://github.com/mobilequickie/LoginWithAmazoniOSSwift
and
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/use-sdk-ios.html

I downloaded the LoginWithAmazon.framework file from the official download page and integrated it in my project as per the instructions given. It now shows up in the Frameworks folder of my project and I can import it in my files.

The problem comes when I add this to the app delegate file :

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return AIMobileLib.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication : UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue)
    }
```

It throws the error : Cannot find 'AIMobileLib' in scope

This is despite my importing LoginWithAmazon in the App Delegate file. I am confused as to why is this happening?

What can be the issue causing this?